# Can`t get preventDefault to work: item.preventDefault is not a function

Tags: javascript, preventdefault

I  try to create a js script That firstly block default and only second time let go to link for mobile menus, but I can not get preventDefault to work, the error is: item.preventDefault is not a function. the others are ok, the .setAttribute is working.

this is my script i tried with no luck:

```js
var hasChild = document.querySelectorAll(".menu-item-has-children a");
hasChild.forEach(setPrevent);

function setPrevent(item) {
  item.setAttribute('data-active', 'false');
  item.addEventListener("click", respButAction);
  item.preventDefault();
  // this.preventDefault();
}

function respButAction(item) {
  isaActive = this.getAttribute('data-active');
  console.log(isaActive);

  if (isaActive == 'false') {
    this.setAttribute('data-active', 'true');
    // item.setAttribute('data-active', 'true');
    item.stopPropagation();
    // this.stopPropagation();
  }
  if (isaActive == 'true') {
    this.setAttribute('data-active', 'false');
    // item.setAttribute('data-active', 'false');
    item.preventDefault();
    //this.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

Comment: `preventDefault` is the member function of event. You can call it inside event handler.

Comment: The issue is in the function `setPrevent(item)`, this item is the DOM, that do not have the function `preventDefault`, if you remove from this method it should work.

Comment: i think you must use `preventDefault` onclick, i.e when there is an event handler method

Comment: You already have `item.preventDefault()` in `respButAction()`. You don't need it in `setPrevent`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as I mentioned in the comment.

The issue is in the method `setPrevent(item)`, here you can't call `item.preventDefault();` because the `item` variable is the actual DOM element.

I would suggest 2 changes:
 1. remove the call in the method `setPrevent(item)`
 2. rename the variable in the method `respButAction(item)`

example:

```
var hasChild = document.querySelectorAll(".menu-item-has-children a");
hasChild.forEach(setPrevent);

function setPrevent(item) {
    item.setAttribute('data-active', 'false');
    item.addEventListener("click", respButAction);
    // remove: item.preventDefault();
}

function respButAction(event) {
    isaActive = this.getAttribute('data-active');
    console.log(isaActive);

    if (isaActive == 'false') {
         this.setAttribute('data-active', 'true');
         event.stopPropagation();
    }
    if (isaActive == 'true') {
         this.setAttribute('data-active', 'false');
         event.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

With this new variable name `event` you avoid confusion with `item` an `event` types, if you see in [the docs](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_preventdefault.asp) from about the `preventDefault` you can understand the difference better

Comment: I need initially to have preventDefault, that`s why I put in setPrevent. 

This way the button initially is active,

Comment: Hi Botond, but the prevent is about the event so you need to prevent in the click, look in the docs `The preventDefault() method cancels the event if it is cancelable, meaning that the default action that belongs to the event will not occur`, if you can, take a look in the docs, maybe you are confusing with the usage of it.